# while installing "pip install python-chess" in a virtual environment on vscode, got full errors about ssl

Tags: visual-studio-code, pip, virtualenv

I am not an expert but a junior developer, and I tried to make an AI for chess, for this I went to vscode, made a folder "`pychess`" in vscode and on my desktop, I activate the virtual env, and then I ran `pip install python-chess`

and I have this :

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/ssl/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/ssl/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/ssl/
ERROR: Operation cancelled by user
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

kinda spent all day to figure out , changing path variables; trying different commands that I even don't remember, and I just don't know what is the problem, when I do "import chess" even if I managed to download it from windows prompt (probably I added 3 times the anaconda path to make it work), even then, it says "seems like package chess is installed on "C....blabla"" but still import chess was not working. So i deleted the chess framework downloaded from windows prompt and hoped that this time it will probably work on my terminal in vscode and inside de v environment, but I was wrong again

Please, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing openssl [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001435926-Installing-OpenSSL-locally-under-your-username)

then you should make sure python is installed and run

```
./configure --with-openssl=/home/username/openssl
```

then finally run this and if there is no output you should be good

```
python3 -m ssl
```